# know object behind another object is fully visible

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have developed scratch card effect.I am stuck at logic of how can I know object got visible which is behind the scratch card image? So that I can show reward screen.

PS: with modifications in this [link](http://studio.openxcell.com/remove-dustfog-object-unity-swipe.html) I able to work this scratch card effect in uGUI.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could go about this. Assuming you know the dimensions of the red "target image" that the user is trying to uncover, you could take a fixed number of samples from the area that the target is under. Once, say, 80% of those samples are transparent (i.e. the target is visible at those positions), you can consider the object visible and show the reward screen.

You can use [GetPixel](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html) to get the individual samples from the scratch texture.